Voila output to html - can't see output file
This is a simple query about the useful voila module in python
I've got a jupyter notebook called voila_testing.ipynb - although it could be any notebook.
It is hosted on Sharepoint and all I want to do is is output the voila results into an html file as not too many people can access the jupyter notebook on our system.
I've tried running it and then using the command line in vscode to run
voila voila_testing.ipynb --template=lab --export=output.html
But although the html page comes up it doesn't generate an output.html file.
Otherwise it would be a simple solution for my dashboard work.

What does the shell/terminal show when you run voila voila_testing.ipynb --template=lab --export=output.html? According to when I run voila --help-all, there is no --export argument. But maybe you have a special version? And as far as I know such an option was rejected by the project, see here. That latter link has details at the end of the thread on a command closer to what you should be trying.

@Wayne To be honest, I used CoPilot and it said it was an option. I didn't check the response from VSCode. Just a hallucination?

My guess is 'yes' on hallucination. Where you ran that command probably says something like [Voila] WARNING | Unrecognized alias: 'export', it will have no effect.

Hello, is the version of voila you are using updated? Or use the command voila voila_testing.ipynb --template=lab --file-output=output.html and see if that works. Also, you need to make sure that the directory where you run the command contains the voila_testing.ipynb file correctly.
